# How to Extract and use the JSESSIONID cookie from firefox browser using selenium webdriver to use same session.

Tags: java, session, selenium-webdriver, httpclient, jsessionid

I am working on the UI Automation using a selenium web driver, I want to test the web services which are filling data in the UI. When I traverse through the UI, I want to test the data which are filled with the UI element of this web service. But selenium doesn't support calling web services, so I am using http client, but as this is two different applications I want to use the same session for selenium web driver and HTTP client. I am using the firebox as my browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assume Wed Driver is initiated properly 
 Cookie cookie= driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID");
 System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract JSESSIONID cookies value from firebug then in httpClient set "Cookie" header like setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+ getSessionId())  to send it in every request.